# GRAILS / GORM: Dynamic multiple joins

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've got a complicated query which I can solve using SQL but I can't find a proper GORM way to do the same.

I have Story objects. Each Story object refers to many Tag objects. It's a unidirectional OneToMany relation:

```
class Story {
...
    Collection tags
    static hasMany = [
        tags: Tag
    ]
...
}
```

Several Tags are considered as being "aliased" (technically using a separate "AliasGroup" table, which is not the problem here).

Now, I want to search for multiple tags. Returned stories have to be tagged with ALL of these tags ("Match All tags"). But also, for each of those tags, an 'aliased' tag should also be accepted.

In SQL I solve that by using a dynmically composed sequence of joins. For example, if there are two tags given, both having several "aliases", the resulting SQL statement looks like this (using the actual SQL row names):

```
select s.id from story 
   join story_tag st1 on s.id = st1.story_id 
   join story_tag st2 on s.id = st2.story_id 
where 
   st1.tag_id in (<list of ids for tag1 and all its aliases>) and
   st2.tag_id in (<list of ids for tag2 and all its aliases>)
```

It's important to understand that this cannot be written as a single join, because then the SAME tag would have to be in both groups of tag lists, which is not what I want.

So, this statement is working fine. But I want to achieve the same thing using grails directly. The GORM documentation on joins is rather terse, but I figured that the feature using an association query and 'and' them together would give the correct result. So I tried:

```
def c = Story.createCriteria()
def stories = c.list {
    and {
        srchTags.each { tag ->
            def ids = []

            tag.aliasGroup.aliases.each { alias ->
                ids << alias.id
            }

            tags {
                inList('id', ids)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if I just use one single tag as input. I.e. the list of aliased tags ids is properly resolved and the statement is working in principle.

But if I use two or more tags, it doesn't work correctly. The code runs, but GORM seems to just create the wrong SQL query, it seems that it again tries to match each tag with all of the match-lists which cannot work.

I realize that this problem is not easy to understand, and it's even more difficult to describe properly.

Does anyone have a solution how to create a proper Grails query for this problem?

Comment: Nothing stopping you from using http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-groovy-sql.html. You should find loads on this if you look around. You could also look at doing a `HQL` query but your hasMany object appears to be an internal Collection ?

Answer (score 0):

In a project at work now I had several sql queries that I could not translate to gorm(criteria, where). With the need to move forward I used native sql queries in grails and everything goes well.

Please have a look at the article [Using Hibernate Native SQL Queries](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-hibernate-native.html) for an explanation of the implementation method.

I know you can not always decide which method to use but having this facility at hand is always useful.

I hope it's useful for you. regards

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, and it's exactly the workaround I'm using, too.

It has some disadvantages though, and I don't like it really. I hoped there'd be a better way...